# Spring MVC and gradle ,origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, gradle

I am new to SpringMVC and gradle. 
Getting error "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Here is my code .let me know how to resolve this issue HTTP 404 .

spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"> 

    <!-- Step 3: Add support for component scanning --> 
    <context:component-scan base-package="springdemo.mvc" /> 

    <!-- Step 4: Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support --> 
    <mvc:annotation-driven/> 

    <!-- Step 5: Define Spring MVC view resolver --> 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"> 
       <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" /> 
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" /> 
    </bean> 

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1"> 

    <display-name>spring-mvc-demo</display-name> 

    <!-- Spring MVC Configs --> 

    <!-- Step 1: Configure Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet --> 
    <servlet> 
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class> 
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mvc-demo-servlet.xml</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 

    <!-- Step 2: Set up URL mapping for Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet --> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: Adding update,when i spring MVC simple program without gradle its working fine. i can able to run on tomcat server available server.Issue is when trying to build war file through Gradle.

Comment: can someone guide me what i need to change in build.gradle to make it run?  
   plugins {
      id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

repositories {
 mavenCentral()
} 

dependencies {
 implementation 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
     
 compileOnly "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

war {
 archiveName = 'springtest1.war'
}

task deployToTomcat(type: Copy) {
 from war.archivePath
 into' 'H:/Tomcat/webapps'
}